# How to show all rows of a table but have a default value if the where statement does not match

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a query that always show all rows of a table, but if the where clause does not match give a default value to the a column.

I have a service table with an N to N relation to a house table. In the middle table I have this columns idHouse, idService, active.

For example I have this:

service:

```
id, name     
1, a  
2, b   
3, c   
4, d
```

house:

```
id  
1  
2
```

house_has_service:

```
idService, idHouse, active  
1, 1, 1  
1, 2, 1  
4, 2, 1
```

I've tried subqueries and all types of joins and I can't get around the problem. This was my first attempt.

```
select  
s.idService id, s.name name, IFNULL(v.active, 0) active  
from house_has_service v 
right join service s on s.id = v.idService  
where  
v.idHouse is null or v.idHouse = (houseId) 
order by s.id
```

> (houseId) is the variable I pass

The result I want should look like this:
houseid = 1

```
id, name, active  
1, a, 1  
2, b, 0  
3, c, 0  
4, d, 0
```

houseid = 2

```
id, name, active  
1, a, 1  
2, b, 0  
3, c, 0  
4, d, 1
```

houseid = 3

```
id, name, active  
1, a, 0  
2, b, 0  
3, c, 0  
4, d, 0
```

Comment: Note that nobody ever uses `right join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.id,
       s.name,
       COALESCE(hhs.active, 0) AS active
    FROM service s
        LEFT JOIN house_has_service hhs
            ON s.id = hhs.idService
                AND hhs.idHouse = @houseID
    ORDER BY s.id;
```